# Numeration count inside a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want do do something like:

```
>enumerate ["banana", "potato", "ice"]
[(1, "banana"), (2, "potato"), (3, "ice")]
```

I wrote:

```
enumerate :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
enumerate [] = []
```

How may I control/manage the int counter ? Is there a way to do that without a support function ?

*Update:* I know about [Zip](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zip_f.html) function. But for matter of study, I want to implement my own zip function.

*Update 2: Currently Code*

This is what I did so far, using a support function. Considering that:

1) I want to implement my own `zip` function;
2) I do not want to change the function struct:

```
   enumerate :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]  

enumerate :: [String]->[(Int,String)]
enumerate [] = []
enumerate list = aux 1 list


aux :: Int->[String]->[(Int, String)]
aux _ [] = []
aux i (x:xs) = [(i, x)] ++ aux (i+1) xs
```

Is it possible to improve this function ? As I don't want to add one more last to the function, so I think support function is the only way to go, right ?

Comment: The last `aux` looks fine. For style, I'd change `[(i,x)] ++ ...` into `(i,x) : ...`.

Comment: you don't need `enumerate [] = []` since you're already handling empty lists in `aux` function.

In fact you can just write `enumerate = aux 1`

Comment: @homam and How  aux function will recognize the list ? And Thanks chi, that worked nice. I thought I could just use `:` in  `elem : list`

Comment: `aux` is a function from `aux :: Int -> [String] -> [(Int, String)]`. Hence `aux 1` is a function from `[String] -> [(Int, String)]`. That has the same signature as your `enumerate` function. Hence `enumerate list = aux 1 list` can be written  as `enumerate = aux 1` by eliminating the `list` argument.

Comment: @homam I tried it and got error ;s `aux is applied with too few arguments`

Comment: https://glot.io/snippets/e71mmhxpcl

Comment: Amazing ! It worked really nice. Ty

Comment: `enumerate` function can operate on a list of any type; the argument doesn't have to be a list of strings. You can define it with a generic type: `enumerate :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]` and `aux :: Int -> [a] -> [(Int, a)]`

Answer (score 5):

Don't be afraid to write a support function, in fact, see it as opportunity: Why the arbitrary starting value 1? Why not have a function

```
>enumerateFrom 42 ["banana", "potato", "ice"]
[(42, "banana"), (43, "potato"), (44, "ice")]
```

Once you have that, `enumerate` is easy.

*Edit*:
Either give your `aux` function a real name, IMHO `enumerateFrom` is good or move it into a `where` clause if you know that already. And listen to chi, use `x : ...` instead of `[x] ++ ...`

Comment: Check that out whenever you can and give me your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function which does this called [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) (`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`). Now for your function you just can pass a list with `1,2,...` as first argument and get your result, e.g.

```
enumerate :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
enumerate = zip [1..]
```

**EDIT:**

If you also want to implement your own `zip` function, just use:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip' _ [] = []
zip' [] _ = []
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y):zip' xs ys
```

You take two lists (`[a]` and `[b]`) and put each element into a tuple. Edge cases are of cores when one of the lists is empty you return an empty list. Otherwise you use pattern matching to get the first element of the list put them into a tuple and call `zip'` again with the tail of the list.

Comment: I know. But I want to implement one... Just for matters of study. Could you give me a hands up ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro So you mean you want to implement your own `zip` function ?

Comment: Yeah... I want to improve my knowledge about recursion. Guess that is a way to go. I should told that at first, sorry about it. I'll update the question

Comment: Nice man ! But what if I don't want to change my function structure. I mean, keep using only the string function.. Then the only solution will be a support function, right ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Yes pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

As you clarified you wanted to implement your own zip:

```
zip' [] _ = []
zip' _ [] = []
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zip' xs ys
```

Comment: just a few seconds too late :)